# DataGridView Column Header change when combobox value is clicked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have an issue creating `DataGridView` and `combobox` in windows form application. I need help in writing the code with a condition when `combobox` value is clicked, `datagridview` column header will change adjusting with the selected `combobox` value. Here is the example picture of my desired application:

Example datagridview when [wages is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TQ1E.png)

Example datagridview when [sales is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2esIw.png)

Thank you for your time and help :D

Comment: Do you have multiple `DataTable` or `List` objects which you want to show in `DataGridView` based on `SelectedItem` of `ComboBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Wages")
{
    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "StoreLoc";
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Month";
    dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Value";
}
else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Sales")
{
    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "StoreName";
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "StoreType";
    dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have changed all properties (like column headers etc). I used it in an application I built, but if I would do it again, I would create two separate grid views, and make one of them visible depending on the combo box selection.

So something like (pseudo code):

```
void ComboBoxedValueChanged(...)
{
   gridViewWages.IsVisible = (comboBoxValue == wages);
   gridViewSales.IsVisible = (comboBoxValue == sales);
 }
```

Comment: your solution is also working, but in my case i only need one grid view. Thanks :)